# Patterns - Event Dispatcher without else if?

Tags: python, design-patterns, event-handling

I'm creating a Python wrapper for the Detours library. One piece of the tool is a dispatcher to send all of the hooked API calls to various handlers.

Right now my code looks like this:

```
if event == 'CreateWindowExW':
    # do something
elif event == 'CreateProcessW':
    # do something
elif ...
```

This feels ugly. Is there a pattern to create an event dispatcher without my having to create an `elif` branch for each Windows API function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One nice way to do this is to define a class which has methods equating to the relevant API function names, plus a dispatch method which dispatches to the correct method. For example:

```
class ApiDispatcher(object):

    def handle_CreateWindowExW(self):
        # do whatever

    def handle_CreateProcessW(self):
        # do this one

    def dispatch(self, event):
        method = getattr(self, 'handle_%s' % event)
        method()
```

Answer (score 2):

Those if's will eventually have to go somewhere. Why not do it like this:

```
handler = get_handler(event)
handler.process()
```

and in the `get_handler` you'd have your ifs, each returning an object which does its work in the `process` method.

An alternative would be a map to callables, like this:

```
def react_to_create_window_exw():
   # do something with event here
   pass

handlers = {
  "CreateWindowExW" : react_to_create_window_exw
}
```

and you would use it like this:

```
handler = handlers[event]
handler()
```

This way you would not use any if/else conditions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the dispatch dict method.

```
def handle_CreateWindowExW():
    print "CreateWindowExW"     
    #do something

events = {
    "CreateWindowExW": handle_CreateWindowExW
}

events[event]()
```

This way, you can just add events without having to add different `if` statements.

Answer (score 1):

Usually in such cases when you have a predefined list of actions to take, use a map e.g.

```
def CreateWindowExW():
    print 'CreateWindowExW'

def CreateProcessW():
    print 'CreateProcessW'

action_map = {
    'CreateWindowExW': CreateWindowExW,
    'CreateProcessW': CreateProcessW
}

for action in ['CreateWindowExW', 'UnkownAction']:
    try:
        action_map[action]()
    except KeyError:
        print action, "Not Found"
```

Output:

```
CreateWindowExW
UnkownAction Not Found
```

so using a map you can create a very powerful dispatcher

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find anything that was as graceful as it could be in this area, so I [wrote something](https://github.com/cjw296/switcheroo) that let's you do:

```
from switcheroo import Switch, default

switch = Switch({
    'foo': lambda x: x+1,
    default: lambda x: x-1,
})

>>> switch['foo'](1)
2
>>> switch['bar'](1)
0
```

There are some other flavours; docs are [here](https://github.com/cjw296/switcheroo/blob/master/README.rst), code is on [github](https://github.com/cjw296/switcheroo/blob/master/switcheroo/__init__.py), package is on [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/switcheroo/).